# Xamarin XAML Issue: Inheriting Type not found in xmlns namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, xamarin, reference

I want a base class for my Popups to inherit from, that handles callbacks.

My approach:
Create a class ("CallbackPopup") that inherits from PopupPage (https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)
Create XAML+CS files that inherit from CallbackPopup

**CallbackPopup:** (My base class for my custom popups)

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class CallbackPopup : PopupPage
    {
        //[...]
    }
}
```

**Inheriting Class - XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<myproject:CallbackPopup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" <!-- throws the error -->
                                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                            xmlns:myproject="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly=MyProject"
                            x:Class="MyProject.Layout.Popups.InheritingPopup">
    <CallbackPopup.Content>
       <!-- [...] -->
    </CallbackPopup.Content>
</myproject:CallbackPopup>
```

**Inheriting Class - CS:**

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyProject.Layout.Popups
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class InheritingPopup: CallbackPopup
    {

    public InheritingPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  //  [...]
}
```

**Error:**

```
Type CallbackPopup not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms
```

I have tested the functionallity of the Popups and it has been successful.
However creating it as a base class and make other popups inherit from it is not working as my error states.
Am I missing something in the XAML declarations, or is inheriting from RG Plugins PopupPage causing the issue?

http://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/the-secret-life-of-a-xaml-page/ states:
"You cannot derive a Xaml defined Page from another Xaml defined page (unless they only define resources and no content)"
May that be the cause of the problem? I don't know, if the RG Plugins PopupPages are Xaml defined pages that define more than resources and content.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should put `myproject` namespace when you initialize `CallbackPopup.Content`. That's what error is trying to tell you about :)

Something like this:

```
<myproject:CallbackPopup.Content>
       <!-- [...] -->
</myproject:CallbackPopup.Content>
```

Comment: You are completely right!!! Thanks a lot, I missed that even tho the RG PopupPages implement it this way as well. Have a nice day